# Entity Framework TPT inheritance - How to get from database?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a BaseTable with TypeId column which is foreign key to Type table. I mapped this into entity framework model by using template per hierarchy pattern.

Now i have a `BaseClass` and two subclasses named `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` and make BaseClass `abstract`.

From one of my page to second page i get an id (which is an id of `BaseClass` of course) and i want to get this object from database.

How i will make my query? Coming id is owned by an Subclass of course.

For example, can i write like this:

```
BaseClass object = provider.getfrombaseclassbyid(id);
```

Can i make a boxing like this? if can, how can i know what is object is really. It is a `Subclass1` or `Subclass2`? How can i know it?

Can you help me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following answers your question, but you can indeed query on a set that respresents abstract entities:

```
BaseClass entity = context.BaseClasses.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
```

Of course the result will never be of type `BaseClass` because no instance of an abstract type can be created. It will either be of type `SubClass1` or `SubClass2` (or `null` if an entity with that `id` doesn't exist). Entity Framework can decide which type has to be used when the object is created by looking either at the value of the discriminator column (for Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) inhericance) or by joining from the base table into the tables of the derived types (for Table-Per-Type (TPT) inheritance).

You can check the materialized type for example by using:

```
string typeName = entity.GetType().Name; // will be "Subclass1" or "Subclass2"
```

Or:

```
if (entity is SubClass1)
    // ...
else if (entity is SubClass2)
    // ...
```

If you know in advance that you want to load an entity of type `SubClass1` you can use the `OfType<T>` operator:

```
SubClass1 entity = context.BaseClasses.OfType<SubClass1>()
    .SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
```

If the entity with the given `id` is not a `SubClass1` but a `SubClass2` instead, the result of this query will be `null`. Otherwise it is guaranteed to be a `SubClass1`.